# Constructors in inheritance

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-inheritance

I have this code:

```
struct V {
    V(int a=0) { std::cout <<"V" << a;}
};
struct A: virtual V {
    A(int a);
};
struct B : virtual V {
    B(int a =8);
};
struct C: A,B {
    C(int a);
};
struct D: C, B{
    D(int);
};

A::A(int i) : V(i) { std::cout << "A"<<i;}
B::B(int i) { std::cout <<"B"<<i;}
C::C(int i): A(i),B(i),V(i) { std::cout <<"C"<<i;}
D::D(int i): C(i) { std::cout <<"D" << i;}

int main()
{

    D d(5); std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> **V0**A5**B5**C5B8D5

I suppose that **B5** is a result of initialization list of `struct C`, in this list there is `V(i)` too, but V prints 0, no 5.

**Question:**
Why result is V0 not V5 ?

Comment: The constructor of a virtual inheritance is only called once, and from the most derived class.